# Hierarchical Voronoi?

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'd like to vary the size of Voronoi cells (from the Voronoi Texture node) depending on a vertex attribute. The final goal is to have larger and smaller scales on a procedural creature's skin, depending on where on the body they are.

Something like the following "hierarchical voronoi" is my goal:
https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Xll3zX

I've tried plugging a varying value into the "Scale" input parameter of the Voronoi, but that results in cells just being stretched (in the direction normal to the gradient of the vertex parameter):
[image]
Here, the scale parameter varies from top to bottom, resulting in the top cells being larger, but stretched from left to right.

Maybe I could port the shadertoy code above to OSL, but I'd like to stick to GPU rendering and use nodes only, if possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: As in your last q. , it's relatively easy to  make a heirarchy like [this](https://imgur.com/a/3CjjnQA), but the problem remains of how to get vertex-data into a space Voronoi can use.. bake into UV?